# DataExtension and canView

Tags: silverstripe

I like to second this question from the forum:
http://www.silverstripe.org/data-model-questions/show/23484

In short:
Is it possible to apply the permission methods:

```
canView, canEdit, canDelete, canCreate etc
```

via DataExtension?

I tried but couldnt succeed yet and i wonder if i am missing something?

Subclassing would probably do, but as there are empty permission methods in DataExtension, of what purpose are they?

```
public function canEdit($member) {
}
```

Comment: Which SilverStripe version?

Comment: sorry, SilverStripe 3.0.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming SS3.0+ the short answer is, it depends.

The straight `DataObject->can[Create|Edit|View|Delete]` methods can't be extended in that fashion, but descendants of `SiteTree` mostly can.

The function of interest here is [`DataObject->extendedCan`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.0/class-DataObject.html#_extendedCan) which is called by all the `SiteTree` can* methods but not the DataObject can* methods.

Of course you can always ensure this method is called in your `DataObject` sub-classes.

Be aware that this can get very complex if multiple extensions are extending these functions. Here is some important documentation from the `DataObject` class:

> Process tri-state responses from permission-alterting extensions.  The extensions are expected to return one of three values:
>
> - false: Disallow this permission, regardless of what other extensions say
> - true: Allow this permission, as long as no other extensions return false
> - NULL: Don't affect the outcome

It's also worth noting that any user with the ADMIN permissions will slip through all of these checks. The only way to change permissions on objects for ADMIN users is sub-classing `DataObject`.

Comment: ok thanx! so my conclusion is: its not possible. i see the complexity of multiple extensions. Subclassing is also not very comfortable because you cant easily add it to already existing DOs.