# CanView effect on DataExtension - Silverstripe 3.1.12

Tags: silverstripe

I'm developing a Silverstripe module module allowing users to subscribe to a website which also sends out a monthly magazine.

There will be 2 levels of user in a single group. All users in this group will have be able to login to the site, but some content will only be visible to those with an active, paid subscription.

I have a DataExtension extending the main Page object. This allows me to have a boolean field to indicate subscriber only content. My intention was to add the "canView" function, which would perform the necessary checks on the user's subscription status to hide the links from inactive members, returning true for admin of course.

```
class MemberPageExtension extends DataExtension {
    static $db = array(
        'SubscribersOnly' => 'Boolean'
    );
    public function canView(){
        // perform subscription checks here
        return false ; // result will be dependent on subscription status
    }
}
```

Unfortunately canView() doesn't seem to be working/available on a DataExtension, so now I'm a little stuck as to how to achieve this.

Is there a way to make the "can" functions available to a DataExtension on a Page, or produce a similar effect without the need for if statements in the templates?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758844/dataextension-and-canview

Answer (score 1):

Citing the [official documentation](http://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/extending/extensions/):

> If the Extension needs to modify an existing method it's a little
>   trickier. It requires that the method you want to customize has
>   provided an Extension Hook in the place where you want to modify the
>   data.

I just checked the `cms/code/model/SiteTree.php` code and I found these lines:

```
// Standard mechanism for accepting permission changes from extensions
$extended = $this->extendedCan('canView', $member);
if($extended !== null) return $extended;
```

So... yes, you can modify the `canView` behavior, and by declaring a `canView` function (as you did).

Your problem is somewhere else: you must show us how `canView` is defined.

#### Addendum

A quick test: I just saved this code as `mysite/code/Page.php` on a bare SilverStripe installation.

```
<?php

class Page extends SiteTree {
}

class Page_Controller extends ContentController {
}

class MemberPageExtension extends DataExtension {

    public function canView(){
        // perform subscription checks here
        return false ; // result will be dependent on subscription status
    }
}

$instance = new Page();
Debug::show($instance->canView());

Page::add_extension('MemberPageExtension');

$instance = new Page();
Debug::show($instance->canView());
```

The first call returns `true`, the second `false`.

Again: your problem resides elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've edited the original post to show how I usually use the `canView()` function. It did not work in this instance however

Comment: The provided code does not show real code: it is just a placeholder function. I just added a code sample that show that `canView` on extensions **works**. It seems you already made up your mind on the problem, and this is veeeery bad for debugging.